# \r\n\r\n Strings Getting Into Plain Text

Tags: php, mysql, plaintext

I am facing an issue of using form input that I need to send as a text email and then put into the database.

When I send it as a text email, the newline characters show up as \r\n\r\n in the plain text email, but do not show up like that when stored in the DB.

I am using PHP/MySQL - what would be the fix to stop the \r\n\r\n characters from showing up in the email that gets sent out?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: how are u sending the mail? using a class or sendmail?

Comment: I am just using the mail function of PHP

Comment: are you writing them inside single quotes ('\r\n') or double quotes ("\r\n")? because, if the first case, they would be displayed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send the email as text/html and use

```
<p> or <br>
```

tags

Comment: It took me a while to understand what you mean, but yeah...its one solution to do a replace string from \r\n to <br />

Comment: I'm not sure if it's safe to send mail as *only* text/html (mostly because of used webmails).

Comment: @binaryLV what do you mean "not safe to send mail as text/html only because of used webmails?"

Comment: @Genadinik, what should be displayed in an email client that does not support text/html, if email has body only in text/html? It might show HTML code in plain text, and to an average user it would look like ancient hieroglyphics. It's better to send emails with 2 bodies - one in text/html, one in text/plain.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause of this might be database sanitizing (like mysqli_real_escape_string). I've done the same mistake by systematically sanitizing even variables that were never passed to the database.